# Macbook Pro oddly unresponsive to trackpad clicks and keyboard, probably caused by zoom

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mojave, trackpad

I expect I'll have to power-cycle the machine, but asking if anybody has any suggestions for the next time this happens.

Symptoms are:

- I can move the mouse around on the screen, but I can't click on anything.
- Nothing responds to the keyboard.
- I can close the lid, let it sleep over night, open the lid, and unlock it with my fingerprint.
- cmd-alt-escape opened the force quit dialog. I can't interact with it or dismiss it now.
- The control-scroll gesture works just fine. I'm pretty sure the system locked up while zooming in the first place.
- No other trackpad gestures work.

Clearly what happened was that the zoom feature grabbed the keyboard and mouse while I was zooming and didn't let go.

I've seen symptoms like this before, and usually had to power-cycle the machine.

I guess my question is: is there a way to force whatever app has grabbed the keyboard and mouse to relinquish it?

---

Edit: problem went away while I was fiddling with the zoom feature. Clearly the zoom feature is where the problem was.